# How is it possible to redirect TRACE statements in MFC to reduce the data stream from AfxDumpStack()?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, trace

I saw from [AfxDumpStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahbxfdc5.aspx) that one can redirect `TRACE` output.

> - **AFX_STACK_DUMP_TARGET_TRACE**   Sends output by means of the TRACE macro. The **TRACE** macro generates output in debug builds only; it generates no output in release builds. *Also, **TRACE** can be redirected to other targets besides the debugger.*

The italics is mine.

I'm programming in C++ from an old application and would like to dump part of the stack using `AfxDumpStack()` which only outputs to `TRACE` or the clipboard.  I want to output only a few of the lines, so I need to process the string prior to output.

How would I accomplish this in the simplest way possible?

**EDIT**

So this is the code for my solution:

```
class hook
{
public:
    hook()
    {
        VERIFY(_CrtSetReportHook2(_CRT_RPTHOOK_INSTALL, Hook) != -1);
        _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
        _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    }
    ~hook()
    {
        _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
        VERIFY(_CrtSetReportHook2(_CRT_RPTHOOK_REMOVE, Hook) != -1);
    }
    static const size_t max_backtrace = 4;    // max calls to view
    static const size_t skip_stack_head = -5; // skips over calls related to AfxDumpStack()
    static size_t line;                       // current line being output from begin of stack dump
    static bool stack_out;                    // currently outputting stack dump
    static int Hook( int reportType, char *message, int *returnValue )
    {
        if (strcmp(message, "=== begin AfxDumpStack output ===\r\n") == 0)
        {
            stack_out = true;
            line = skip_stack_head;
        }
        else if (strcmp(message, "=== end AfxDumpStack() output ===\r\n") == 0)
        {
            OutputDebugString("\r\n");
            stack_out = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (strcmp(message, "\r\n") == 0) // AfxStackDump() sends CRLF out on separate calls
            {
                if (!stack_out || line < max_backtrace-1)
                {
                    OutputDebugString("\r\n\t");
                }
                ++line;
            }
            else if (!stack_out || line < max_backtrace)
            {
                OutputDebugString(message);
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
};
size_t hook::line     = -1;
bool   hook::stack_out = false;

static hook junk;
```

The only problem is that the call to `AfxDumpStack()` requires a spawning of a thread.  If called too much, this will kill the performance of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `TRACE` calls `OutputDebugString`.

You could use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx), which captures `OutputDebugString` output and has an option to log it to a file.

It doesn't seem to be possible to directly send the output to a file other than by changing the application, e.g. by hooking the output with [`_CrtSetReportHook2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94a21kwy.aspx).

Internally, MFC uses [`_CrtDbgReport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hyw4sy7.aspx) to output its `TRACE` messages.  You can call [`_CrtSetReportMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448.aspx) to specify where its output should go.  Having done this you can call [`_CrtSetReportFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a68f826y.aspx) to specify the win32 file handle (as returned by `CreateFile`).

Comment: I know about `DebugView` and and `OutputDebugString()`.  My question wasn't related to that.  It was how do I redirect the `TRACE` data stream to something else without using `.NET`.

Comment: Are you talking about MFC trace?  The article you linked to is talking about redirecting output from the .Net Debug and Trace classes, which are something else entirely.  Did you try the INI file approach?

Comment: No, I didn't try the INI approach as it would output too much data.  I want only maybe the top 3 stack frames output.  And yeah, I must have been asleep when I looked at that page's Trace command. :(

Comment: Fixed reference to where I originally thought that I could redirect the `TRACE` output.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the INI file article.  It can modify the output but it cannot redirect it.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well, this is close.  I want to now disable the default handler.  Can't seem to do it using `_CrtSetReportHook()` and I don't know the original handler so there's no pointer for me to use with `_CrtSetReportHook2()`.

Comment: I've added another paragraph with a simpler method.  Hopefully that's it!

Comment: Gah!  Looks like it works but it seems that every time `AfxDumpStack()` is executed it spawns a thread, killing the application's performance. :(  But, using `_CrtSetReportHook2()` in conjunction with `_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE); _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);` to disable the default handler, did do what I asked.  Thanks.